# Problem with using depended spinner (Multiple spinner) in android

Tags: android, arrays, filter, android-spinner

I'm trying to populate value of the next spinner from the previous spinner. In this case, what I did yet is generating all values inside the spinner means, no matter which value I select in the previous spinner it is always showing all values in the next spinner. I'm using five spinners that needs to populate values according to the previous one. Here I'm using a library for the spinner. The library is as follows.

```
'com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3.1'
```

Here I'm sharing my whole code/class for your consideration. There is no error and I get all values in respective spinner but I want to get values according to the previous one. here is my code.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner;

public class Catchment extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

public ArrayAdapter<String> regionAdapter;
public ArrayAdapter<String> districtAdapter;
public ArrayAdapter<String> upzAdapter;
public ArrayAdapter<String> unionAdapter;
public ArrayAdapter<String> villageAdapter;
public String[] Region = {"1", "2",
};
public String[] District = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8",};
public String[] Upz = {"1","2"...."23";
public String[] Union = {"1","2"...."25"..."50"...."115"};
public String[] Village = { "1","2"...."25"..."50"...."150"...."500"...."947"   };
Button catchment_code;
SearchableSpinner spinner_region, spinner_district, spinner_upz, spinner_union, spinner_village;
String[] region_code;
String[] district_code;
String[] upz_code;
String[] union_code;
String[] vill_code;
int positions;
String test;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_catchment);

    spinner_region = (SearchableSpinner) findViewById(R.id.region);
    spinner_district = (SearchableSpinner) findViewById(R.id.district);
    spinner_upz = (SearchableSpinner) findViewById(R.id.upz);
    spinner_union = (SearchableSpinner) findViewById(R.id.union);
    spinner_village = (SearchableSpinner) findViewById(R.id.village);

    catchment_code = findViewById(R.id.catchment_code);


    // Set spninner adapter
    regionAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Region);
    districtAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, District);
    upzAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Upz);
    unionAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Union);
    villageAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Village);

    //Set dropdown to the spinner
    regionAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    districtAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    upzAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    unionAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    villageAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    //assign to spinner
    spinner_region.setAdapter(regionAdapter);
    spinner_district.setAdapter(districtAdapter);
    spinner_upz.setAdapter(upzAdapter);
    spinner_union.setAdapter(unionAdapter);
    spinner_village.setAdapter(villageAdapter);

    spinner_region.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    spinner_district.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    spinner_upz.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    spinner_union.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    spinner_village.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    if (parent.getId() == R.id.region) {
        positions = spinner_region.getSelectedItemPosition();
        region_code = this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.region_code);
        //Toast.makeText(this, region_code[positions], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if (parent.getId() == R.id.district) {
        positions = spinner_district.getSelectedItemPosition();
        district_code = this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.district_code);
        //Toast.makeText(this, district_code[positions], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if (parent.getId() == R.id.upz) {
        positions = spinner_upz.getSelectedItemPosition();
        upz_code = this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.upz_code);
        //Toast.makeText(this, upz_code[positions], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if (parent.getId() == R.id.village) {
        positions = spinner_village.getSelectedItemPosition();
        vill_code = this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.village_code);
        //Toast.makeText(this, vill_code[positions], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    if (parent.getId() == R.id.union) {
        positions = spinner_union.getSelectedItemPosition();
        union_code = this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.union_code);
        //Toast.makeText(this, union_code[positions], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if (!(vill_code == null || region_code == null || district_code == null || upz_code == null ||
            union_code == null)) {
        test = region_code[positions] +
                district_code[positions] +
                upz_code[positions] +
                union_code[positions] + vill_code[positions];
        Toast.makeText(this, test, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    catchment_code.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Catchment.this, Participant_Details.class);
            intent.putExtra("catment_code", test);
            startActivity(intent);


        }
    });

    //Toast.makeText(this, union_code[positions]+upz_code[positions], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Catchment.this, SplashScreen.class);
    Catchment.this.startActivity(intent);
    Catchment.this.finish();}
}
```

So how can I get rid of this problem? I need help.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring all adapter at once in onCreate().

Instead declare just first adapter with values in onCreate() and declare other adapters with empty values.

```
        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     --------;
     // Set spninner adapter
        regionAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Region);
        districtAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new String[]());
        upzAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new String[]());
        unionAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new String[]());
        villageAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new String[]());

------
       spinner_region.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```

Now on itemSelectedListener, filter the desired values if needed and add the values to the next required adapter and notify the values along with adding listener to next spinner(adding listener is up to you, how you want to handle the things)

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
      if (parent.getId() == R.id.region) {
     positions = spinner_region.getSelectedItemPosition();
     String[] filteredDistrict = District.filter(Region[position]) // District.filter is not any predefined function, assuming some filter needed for selected Districts
     districtAdapter.addValues(filteredDistrict);
     districtAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
     spinner_district.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}
}
```

Other than that filtering logic depends on your usecase.

Comment: thank you for feedback but unfortunately *District.filter* this is not working. Any suggestion?

Comment: This will be some function that you have to define, to filter the District list as per Region selection.

Comment: can you please help me with an example please?

Comment: OK, lets suppose you have some mapping between Regions, District and so on.  So if you have Regions as {"2","3", "5"} and Districts as {"2", "4", "6", "3", "9", "5", "10"}, than add a filter that maps the district value as divisible by selected region value, so if you select "2" as region than filtered District values will become {"2", "4", "6", 10} . Hope this helps

Comment: I got this @Sunny but I'm confused about how to do that?

Comment: If you provide me absolute data than only I would be able to help further

Comment: hello there...the above code is direct my class what I'm using.  i have another xml in which i have 5 array each od them contain 947 item.